# When i add carousel in modal , close button is not working in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular6

I want to add a carousel in a modal popup, so i have add carousel it is working fine.

But when tried to to close the model using close button , it is not working.

[Link to stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1gvgm6)

[image: gif of modal]

Any suggestions on how to make work of close button?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like your example works good. I can close the modal via `x`, `close` buttons or when I click outside the modal.

Comment: I have added .gif to my question @IrinaPotapova. please look at it once

Comment: is it possible to update your demo with the carousel? Sorry, but I can't find it in demo.

Comment: usually next/prev controls have a big vertical area (so, no only arrows can switch between slides of the carousel). Please check `.carousel-control-next` element in dev-tools. I hope you just need to move your carousel a little bit down in modal.

Comment: Hi @IrinaPotapova,  I have carousel in the demo, you can check the html page in stackblitz, I don't understand why it is not showing up there and i figured out the problem that is beacuse of `.carousel-control-next`  can't we decrease the height of that element?

Comment: sorry, but that example doesn't have the problem you've described, prev/next arrows are not visible, and close button works properly. Could you please update your stackblitz demo with real styles to have a modal like on your .gif (with arrows and non working "x" button)? Otherwise there is nothing to fix.

Comment: please check the answer below. If it will not help, please provide updated stackblitz demo with styles and behaviour like on your .gif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to change css for prev/next arrows:

```
.carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
    height: 30px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

`top` and `transform` will set arrow icon vertically centered. You can change these values easly depending on your needs. And now prev/next controls will have only 30px height. Hope it helps.

Comment: @KeerthiReddyYeruva, no problem